# How to completely remove a custom theme from magento

Tags: magento, themes, uninstallation, removeall

May i know how to remove a custom theme from MAGENTO completely.

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2

and how to disable it completely.

What i did and face problems.

I have two custom themes say Theme 1 and Theme 2.
Theme one is compatible with 1.7.0.2 and theme 2 with 1.6.x

I installed theme 1 as prescribed in the document.

then i installed theme 2 as per the document and make changes in the System>configuration>design to make necessary changes.

My problem is that-

1. few pages are showing theme 1 and few are theme 2.
2. the home page and one or two product page shows theme1 and few other product pages and checkout page shows theme 2.
3. Then i remove each and every individual file of theme 2. (That i don't want to opt for, as it is very time consuming and problem may occur)
4. Now, i again reinstall the theme 1 just in case if i haven't remove any wrong file of theme 1 itself. ( I follow the same process in documentation)
5. Now the problem is Magento default theme is overtaking few pages of my custom theme 1.

The problem never gets end up here at all.

That's why i am looking for a solution where i can completely remove or uninstall a custom theme.
If not, i want to disable any theme, if possible.

I want to know can we test multiple themes on MAGENTO and can switch between them.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have no custom themes set at the product or category level (which if you don't know what I mean, you shouldn't have), all you should have to do is change the values in `System > Configuration > Design`. As far as removing them, if they were installed properly, i.e. they are their own unique folders in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}` and `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}`. If you are seeing different themes on different pages though, this is probably just a caching issue. Make sure you completely refresh all caches in `System > Cache Management`.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the downloaded package of your custom theme and not down all the locations of the folders under the "app" folder. Now go to your root magento directory and delete all those folders which are associated with your custom theme in app/code/local, app/code/community, app/etc/modules, app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme, skin/frontend/default/yourtheme/, js/yourtheme, media/yourtheme.
Delete all the folders of your custom theme from these location and delete the "cache" folder located in the "var" folder in your root directory.
You can now see that your custom theme is completely removed from both the backend and the frontend of your magento store...
worked for me every time...